# Brushless Motor Encoder Read?

Tags: motor, encoder, motor-controller

I have this a **MegaMo SY3056** [BLDC Spec.PDF](http://www.megamo.com.hk/BLDC%20spec.pdf)
[image: MegaMo SY3056]

And beside the cables that are connected to the ESC i have thses encoder cables:
[image: Encoder Cables]

How can i read this encoder? and what values do i get?

**Can i know the absolut position of the motor ?**

Comment: Without a proper data sheet, who can tell?  All we can glean from the one you have there is that it has a hall-effect sensor.

Comment: maybe the manufacturer has a separate generic data sheet for the sensors

Comment: Yes, but i couldn't find the datasheet anywhere ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a data sheet for a different MegaMo motor.  It seems to have similar wiring, with the following specs related to the encoder connector:

```
A Hall Sensor         Blue 
B Hall Sensor         Green 
C Hall Sensor         Yellow
+6V Logical Supply    Red 
GND Logical           Black
```

(from the [BL2235 datasheet](http://www.megamo.com.hk/BL2235.pdf))

This should at least get you started on reading the encoder.  Couldn't find anything more detailed about the sensors/resolution.  Hopefully you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

With no proper datasheet available looks like you will have to guess (I had a look, very little on the website - you could try sending an email to the address given there)

Is there an encoder attached to the motor also? How many wires are coming from the motor in total?

A few thoughts...

If the wires going into the casing in the top picture are the main motor connections:
I think the red is for V+, black for ground. This is easily confirmed by briefly applying power and see if the motor turns. 
The other three(?) are likely to be for the hall effect sensor - possibly white for V+, green for ground and [unseen wire] for output.
It would be wise to use a current limited supply if you have one (e.g. bench supply)
If not I would put a 100-500 ohm resistor in series with the V+ to the sensor (whichever wire you are trying)
The sensor output may be open drain, so a 1-10k resistor from the output to V+ maybe required.

Not sure about the encoder wires without more info.

More photos/explanation of wiring/electronics (can you partially dismantle to get a better look if necessary?) might help to guess better.